# How to change CSS with PHP and create a cookie in the same place

Tags: php, html, css, cookies

So, I have a bit of code and it basically checks to see if a `cookie` is created and if it is, then set an `element` to `display: none;` and if it isn't, then set an `element` to `display: block;` and create a `cookie` (this way, as long as the `cookie` remains, the display will only change that first time).

Unfortunately, I ran into a dilemma and I think I know why. I know `cookie`s have to be called *before* all other things relating to HTML. But any CSS has to change in the `head` or the `body` (in this case, the `body`). So, I am wondering how I can get this done and if it isn't possible/isn't a good idea, what a better solution might be.

Also, I thought about having it check if the `cookie` has been created before and do the whole `cookie`-creating part and then later on have the it check to see if the `cookie` exists and if it doesn't, change the `element` to `display: block;`, but this wouldn't work because it would create a cookie the first time it went to the page before it even changed the CSS.

Code:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["beenToCyanCoding"])) {
    echo '
        <style type="text/css">
            #welcomeToCyanCoding {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>';
}
else {
    echo '
        <style type="text/css">
            #welcomeToCyanCoding {
                display: block;
            }
        </style>';
    setcookie("beenToCyanCoding", date("m/d/y"), time() + 10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60, "/");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable then echo it in the head like this.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["beenToCyanCoding"])) {
$style= "<style type=\"text/css\">#welcomeToCyanCoding {display:none;}</style>";
} else {
$style= "<style type=\"text/css\">#welcomeToCyanCoding {display: block;}</style>";
setcookie("beenToCyanCoding", date("m/d/y"), time() + 10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60, "/");
}
```

And in your head

```
<head><?php echo $style; ?></head>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
 // At the top of the page
 if(!isset($_COOKIE["beenToCyanCoding"])){

     // Create cookie only if it does not exist
     setcookie("beenToCyanCoding", date("m/d/y"), time() + 10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60, "/");

     // Save the cookie to a variable. Use the variable 
     // to display either none or block in the CSS defination.
     $cookie_exist = $_COOKIE["beenToCyanCoding"];

 }
?>

 <style type="text/css">
    #welcomeToCyanCoding{
        display: <?php if(isset($cookie_exist)){ echo 'none'; }else{ echo 'block'; } ?>;
    }
 </style>
```